# Wifi drops out only when I go to the play store? Any fixes?

Tags: wi-fi, nexus-7

On my Nexus 7 whenever I go to the Play store I get a "no connection" error and I look up and the wifi icon shows me there is no connection. I leave the Play app and go look in setting and before I know it, I have wifi again. I got to Chrome and sure enough, wifi is working fine. Then I go back to the Play store and the wifi icon goes blank and no connection. In settings I have 4.2.1.

Comment: Can you enclose the logcat of when that happens?

Comment: It there any personal information in the logcat? I'll see if I can get it.